# find exact string match and replace it in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is there a (supposedly) simple way to get an exact match when using the replace function in SQL Server 2012?  (I'm open to other searching possibilities as well, of course)

For example, I'm using the following code to grab all the objects in a DB containing  'texter' in it at some point:

```
select OBJECT_NAME(object_id) name,
       OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) code,
       type
into #tester
from sys.objects
where OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%texter%'
```

This doesn't seem to differentiate between .texter, @texter or stupidtexter.

and so if I use:

```
update #tester 
set code = REPLACE(code, 'texter', 'bluenose')
where code LIKE '%texter%'
```

It's going to replace any variant of 'texter' with 'bluenose'

Let's assume I only want to replace the ' texter' and '.texter' versions of this and nothing else (noting that within each object it is possible that  @texter or stupidtexter may also be present in the object code).

Is there a way I can differentiate between the variants of 'texter', @texter and stupidtexter?

Thanks

Comment: use `=` or `IN` operator to find exact matches, to update rows only where texter or .texter then you would use `WHERE Code IN ('texter', '.texter')` or you can do something like `WHERE Code = 'texter' OR Code = '.texter'`

Comment: In the replace statement where 'texter' is could you not just use ' texter' and repeat the operation with '.texter' ?

Comment: @awright18 I could, but then I'd need to use 2 update statements which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: @M.Ali  With "Code" being a stored procedure, the stored procedure can contain 'texter', '.texter', '@texter' AND 'stupidtexter', and the  replace would appy equally to all of them.

Comment: What are you actually doing here? Seems like importing the database into an SSDT Project and using the rename refactoring might work. Or at least you could then search the object definitions using regular expressions.

Comment: @Martin Smith I'm trying to switch all the instances of one column in the database with another, while at the same time avoiding all the references to it anywhere else so that the recompilation of a fair number of reports isn't necessary.  I'll take a look at the SSDTs and see if I can figure out if they can help me.

Comment: Should work then http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/03/refactoring-with-ssdt

Comment: You wouldn't have to do 2 updates, just do a nested replace. replace(REPLACE(code, '.texter', 'bluenose'), ' texter', 'bluenose')

Comment: @SeanLange You're right!  My brain has apparently baked in the light of my monitors too long today.  Thanks very much!

Comment: and apologies @awright18 you pointed me in the right direction and I just missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was:

```
replace(REPLACE(code, '.texter', 'bluenose'), ' texter', 'bluenose')
```

Thanks to Sean Lange for the answer!