# Replace multiple instances of exact word in a string

Tags: sql, postgresql, pattern-matching

I have an address column in a table where I want to replace a certain word. But my query also replaces partial matches:

```
select replace('the bthe the them', 'the', 'abc')
```

for above example, desired output should be:

```
abc bthe abc them
```

but the output is:

```
abc babc abc abcm
```

How to solve this?

Comment: look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27953391/find-exact-string-match-and-replace-it-in-sql-server

Comment: @PatrickTucci  postgre SQL

Comment: @vkp answer is not producing the desired result.

Comment: Replace case sensitive? Is  a plain space (`' '`) the only possible white space in your strings, or can there be others? [There are many!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) What about `'the.'` or `'the-'` etc.?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter there could be other possibilities also but all other      the  would have either a trailing, leading or both spaces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT REPLACE(' ' + column + ' ', ' the ', ' abc ')
FROM table
```

output:

```
abc bthe abc them
```

I was assuming that you would be selecting from a table when replacing the values in the strings. So 'column' is the column in your table you are selecting from that contains the value you are wanting to use the replace function on.

Comment: I don't know how to use it on a column named address, could you please give an example where we can apply this query on a column.

Comment: @Anuj edited it to show how to use when selecting from a table.

Comment: okay, I think this could be the answer. Let me test this on my actual data set and get back to you.

Comment: If the string has leading or trailing spaces,  you are loosing that info

Comment: This is not exactly correct. [As commented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269759/replace-multiple-instances-of-exact-word-in-a-string#comment50537137_31270136) under the earlier duplicate. @Nuri provides a [correct solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31270742/939860) for the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

```
select trim(replace(' the bthe the them ', ' the ', ' abc '))
```

Comment: @jarh The output of this query is "abcbtheabcthem"

Comment: This would fail for any other white space or stop characters. Also, leading and trailing spaces have just magically popped up in your answer.

Comment: @jarlh this is not correct answer I think, I don't have any leading and or trailing space in my example.

Comment: Yes, I've added a leading and a trailing space, to make sure leading and trailing the's are replaced too. Can be done with concat as well, e.g. trim(replace(' ' || 'the bthe the them' || ' ', ' the ', ' abc '))

Comment: That would also trim *pre-existing* trailing and leading spaces, which may be a sneaky problem.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, yes, I know, it's perhaps a problem - or a feature!

Comment: That's why we typically add *explanation* to a presented solution to point out "features" etc. This variant would not exhibit the last feature: `right(left(replace(' ' || 'the bthe the them' || ' ', ' the ', ' abc '), -1), -1)`. Still only applicable for a limited set of strings. The regex solution is more expensive, but also covers all possible cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
SELECT regexp_replace('the bthe the them', '\ythe\y', 'abc','g')
```

\y : means word boundary

flag g: for replacing all occurences

Comment: Exactly what I was about to post. Or `'\mthe\M'`. [Details in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE)

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple function as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_ReplaceCharacters]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @MatchExpression VARCHAR(255),
    @Replace VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE Charindex(@MatchExpression, @String)>0
       SET @String = REPLACE(@String, @MatchExpression, @Replace)
    RETURN @String
END
GO
```

Then to reference it:

```
select dbo.fn_ReplaceCharacters('the bthe the them', 'the', 'abc')
```

Which returns the result:

abc babc abc abcm